# Queries works in SmartPhone when I download my App from Android Studio, but not from Play Store

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-play

Queries of my application works in emulator of Android Studio or in SmartPhone, but when I download app from Play Store it don't make queries. App do inserts in the collections, creating new documents. For example when I sing up with a new user, it is created.

I copied SHA-1 keys from Play Store console to Cloud Firestore SDK configuration:

- Application signing key certificate
- Upload key certificate

My security rules of Cloud Firestore are:

[image: Security Rules (Cloud Firestore)]

I don't exceed the limit of my quote of Cloud Firestore:

[image: Quotes Cloud Firestore]

Comment: At start, app worked from playstore. But one day the queries stopped. It begins when people start to test app.

Comment: I have uploaded 4 versions